# Getting the definition of a CLR Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, ddl, sqlclr

I wrote a CLR stored procedure (to send emails, and not depend from DatabaseMail, as I was told it was more safer).

It works as expected. The thing I want to learn now is how to get the definition from a CLR object (CLR SP, CLR scalar function, etc).

I already tried with:

- sys.sql_modules,
- sys.system_sql_modules,
- OBJECT_DEFINITION()

But it returns a null definition.

Is there any other way to get the definition of a CLR object?

Comment: If you wrote it, you have the source code. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @BenThul Not much, really; just trying to learn as much as I can.
I'm learning SQL CLR on my own, so I found it odd when I was checking sys.sql_modules looking for a scalar function (the SQL one), and I noticed there was nothing about CLR objects in there. Which led to me wondering if it was actually possible to get it.

Comment: @soulblazer I just updated my answer to clarify one point and added a link to a series of articles I am writing to help people learn how to work with SQLCLR :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLCLR objects have no T-SQL code so there is nothing to store that could be retrieved using the `sys.* _sql_modules` DMVs or the `OBJECT_DEFINITION()` built-in function.

If you want the underlying .NET code, that is in the Assembly, which is found in: `sys.assembly_files`.

```
SELECT *
FROM   sys.assembly_files
WHERE [file_id] = 1;
```

If you don't have the source code, that can be extracted by disassembling the Assembly.

If you want the `CREATE PROCEDURE ... AS EXTERNAL NAME ... ;`  statement then that would need to be pieced together from several DMVs: `sys.assembly_modules`, `sys.types`, `sys.parameters`, `sys.columns`. You would also need to use `OBJECT_NAME` and `OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME` built-in functions. If you are trying to recreate a `CREATE TYPE` statement, then you will need to check the `sys.assembly_types` DMV.

Also, to learn more about working with SQLCLR in general, please see the series of articles I am writing on this topic on SQL Server Central: [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/) (free registration is required to read their content).